# Referencing the name of the unique id generated by push in angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

How do I reference in the template the unique id provided when I push an object to firebase.

I have this:

```
 -JGfp5eaDEk2_oB_Wnkc
     category_id: xxxx
     content: xxx
     created: xxx
     title: xxx
 -JGfqwXgeHSksqcmeGEv
     category_id: xxx
     content: xxx
     created: xxx
    title: xxx
```

I got that by using:

```
var ref = firebaseRef('/types');
$scope.types = $firebase(ref);
```

Now I want to create a link in my template that is something like:

```
<a href="update/JGfqwXgeHSksqcmeGEv">Update</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="(key, value) in types">
<a href="update/{{key}}">Update</a>
</li></ul>
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: wow!, i struggle on searching for angularFire solution, I didn't thought the solution wasn't that far off

Comment: this works, but I'm wondering how to actually get a slug instead

Answer (score 0):

I have created a ***[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TAXmsQlSkYhY2isCKIAw?p=preview)*** for you which is a simplest CRUD application uses Angularjs + Firebase + Bootstrap.

Also fork + Star this ***[git](https://github.com/TUSHAR4541/Angulrjs-CRUD-with-bootstrap-modal)***